# Calculating mean from column values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want a result-set as below from a table:

[image]

I tried query:

```
select sdate, sum(PG)/sum(PT)*100 AS Score, avg(score) as Mean from table
```

but I am not getting the correct Mean.

Mean is: sum of all scores / total number of scores.

I want to show mean as computed column. In the above result-set, total of scores is 309 and when divided by 4 (total number of rows) it gives 77.25.

I want to display the result as shown in the result-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
SELECT sdate, 
       SUM(PG)/SUM(PT)*100 AS Score, 
       (SELECT AVG(score) FROM table) AS Mean 
FROM table
```

This should set the mean to the average score across the entire table. If you have `WHERE` clauses for filtering, you would have to place them in both the subquery and the main query.

**EDIT**

If the original SQL statement has a `GROUP BY`, as it sounds like it does, then you could use the following query to achieve what you're looking for:

```
SELECT sdate, 
       SUM(PG)/SUM(PT)*100 AS score, 
       (SELECT AVG(score) 
        FROM (SELECT CAST(SUM(PG)/SUM(PT)*100 AS FLOAT) AS score 
              FROM table 
              GROUP BY sdate) scores) AS Mean
FROM table
GROUP BY sdate
```

It's not pretty, but I believe it'll accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried adding the sub-query as above, but it is not recognizing the alias name 'Score' in the sub-query.

Comment: Ah. Didn't click that the two Scores were the same. If I understand the table structure correctly, then it looks like you've got a `GROUP BY Date` happening, and you're calculating the scores by date. If this is the case, I'll update the query to utilize that logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mean DECIMAL(5,2);

SELECT @mean = AVG(score) FROM dbo.table;

SELECT sdate, score, Mean = @mean FROM dbo.table;
```

Comment: Why does it need to be "a single query"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

as you need to show avg in each row , i am using subquery to generated that avg each time .

```
create table mean
(
  d date,
  score int 

)

insert into mean values ('01/01/2013',50),('02/01/2013',60)
                       ,('03/01/2013',40),('04/01/2013',30)
                       ,('05/01/2013',20),('06/01/2013',20)


SELECT d,score,(select sum(score)/count(*) from mean) from mean
```

[SQL FIDDLE LINK](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/307ff/2)

but it will be good if you count avg first and use that variable in your select statement

```
SELECT d,score,
ISNULL((select CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(score))/count(*) ) from @mean) ,0) as mean from @mean
```